# Expand the function into a Maclaurin series and find the radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Well, I've solved similar problems before, but this one isn't giving me anything to work with as every higher level derivative keeps getting more unpleasant.

Expand the function into a Maclaurin series and find the radius of convergence:

$f(x)=\ln\sqrt[5]{3+x-6x^2-2x^3}$

Could someone help out?

Comment: What's to the  power $1/5$? The log or its argument?

Comment: The argument, it's a root five, just didn't know how to write it out with the script. @Bernard

Answer (score 2):

Just use the fact that\begin{align}\log\left((3+x-6x^2-2x^3)^{1/5}\right)&=\frac15\log\bigl((x+3)(1-2x^2)\bigr)\\&=\frac15\left(\log(3)+\log\left(1+\frac x3\right)+\log\left(1-2x^2\right)\right).\end{align}Now, you only have to expand $\log\left(1+\frac x3\right)$ and $\log\left(1-2x^2\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Try to factorize a polynomial, it is easy. Then you arrive at the sum of three logarithms. If you know the expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ (easy), you could easily find what you are looking for.